# Why is bean only created when main method is placed at the beginning of the class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application whose entry point is the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {

    @Bean(name = "firstApi")
    private static RestApiProxy getFirstApi(@Value("${midtier.host}") String host,
            @Value("${midtier.port}") int port) {
        String baseURI = "/cesmidtier/api";
        return new FirstApi("http", host, port, baseURI, new RequestContextHolder());
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondApi")
    private static RestApiProxy getSecondApi(@Value("${yodlee.host}") String host,
            @Value("${yodlee.port}") int port, @Value("${yodlee.baseURI}") String baseURI,
            @Value("${proxy}") String proxyURI) {
        return new SecondApi("https", host, port, baseURI, proxyURI);
    }

    @Bean(name = "thirdApi")
    private static RestApiProxy getThirdApi(@Value("${amexopen.host}") String host,
            @Value("${amexopen.port}") int port, @Value("${proxy}") String proxyURI) {
        return new ThirdApi("https", host, port, "/", proxyURI);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("Test-Mocked")
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logger() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(5120);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "security.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public AuthorizeHelper authorizeHelper(final ProfileService profileService, final JWTHandler jwtHandler,
            final APIGatewayHandler apiGatewayHandler,
            @Value("${security.permittedClientServices}") String[] permittedClientServices) {
        System.out.println("######################################### 111111111111 ");
        return new DefaultAuthorizeHelper(profileService, jwtHandler, apiGatewayHandler, permittedClientServices);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "security.enabled", havingValue = "false")
    public AuthorizeHelper authorizeHelper() {
        System.out.println("######################################### 2222222222222 ");
        return new NullAuthorizeHelper();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see the class has 2 methods with similar name:

(i)  authorizeHelper(...) with arguments

(ii) authorizeHelper()    without arguments

When I start the application with security=false, then everything work as expected (the application goes into the second authorizeHelper method, the one without arguments).

**Problem:**
But, when I start the application with security=true, the application does not create the expected bean (it does NOT go into the first authorizeHelper method, the one with arguments).

**Solutions** I've found:

1.If I name both methods differently, then this problem disappears.

2.If I put the main method at the beginning of the class (as opposed to the end of the class) then the problem also disappears!

**Question** *Why does the position of the main method seem to play a role in the bean instantiation when both authorizeHelper method have the same name ?*

Comment: Could you please try to remove more stuff from your code? Maybe you will come to even more minimal reproducible example, where it will be better visible. Are the methods getFirstApi(), getSecondApi() etc. really needed to reproduce your strange behaviour?